# Is a where clause that is always true optimized away in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

For SELECT queries generated by my program, I want to always have a WHERE clause, even if there are no conditions. I know I can use WHERE 1=1 e.g., but I can not find a definite answer to whether that WHERE clause will be optimized away. I use SQL Server 2008 or newer ones.

Can I trust SQL Server to be just as fast with WHERE 1=1 as with no WHERE clause at all?

Comment: Yes.  Even if the clause is not optimized away, the performance difference would be so minuscule that you probably could not measure it.

Comment: Your requirement sounds like you are concatenating strings to build your sql query. Don't do that. Instead use parameterized queries to prevent sql injection (and other issues).

Comment: for dynamic where conditions in queries, this is a good read: [Catch-all queries - Gail Shaw](http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/) as well as this: [Dynamic Search Conditions - Erland Sommarskog](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html)

Comment: @TimSchmelter Always good advice, but this is a tool only available to our developers who all have free access to make whatever queries they'd like anyway. They needn't bother with SQL injection.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know `Where 1=1` will be completely ignored by the optimizer. You can check that in execution plan.

```
select * from tablename where 1=1
```

should be same as

```
select * from tablename
```

Both should have identical execution plan with full table/index scan, meaning both the queries are treated in same way